# Call `atexit` when linking to libc dynamically on Linux

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, racket, dynamic-linking

If I have the following program written in C (compiled with GCC on Debian 8.7), I am able to call `atexit()` as you would expect:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void exit_handler(void) {
    return;
}

int main () {
    atexit(exit_handler);
    return 0;
}
```

And when I compile and run it:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
```

Outputs nothing, just as you would expect. In fact, when I run `ldd`, I get:

```
$ ldd a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffbe592000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe07d3a8000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe07d753000)
```

However, `libc` does not seem to have any symbols for `atexit`, amd only has`__cxa_atexit` and `__cxa_threaded_atexit_impl`:

```
$ nm --dynamic /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep 'atexit'
0000000000037d90 T __cxa_atexit
0000000000037fa0 T __cxa_thread_atexit_impl
```

As you would then expect, if I try to link to `libc` dynamically, I cannot actually call `atexit()`, such as in the following Racket program which links to `libc` and tries to find `atexit`:

```
#lang racket

(require ffi/unsafe)

(get-ffi-obj 'atexit (ffi-lib "libc" '("6")) (_fun (_fun -> _void) -> _int))
```

Giving the output:

```
$ racket findatexit.rkt
ffi-obj: couldn't get "atexit" from "libc.so.6" (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: undefined symbol: atexit)
```

What I want to know here is:

1. If `libc` does not have any symbol for `atexit` on Linux, why can I still call it from a C program?
2. Is there any way I can call `atexit` or a similar function dynamically on Linux?

(I should note that `atexit` does appear to be a symbol on OS X, so its just Linux that seems unusual here.)

Edit:

At the suggestion of @Jonathan, I also ran:

```
$ gcc -c test.c
$ nm test.o
                 U atexit
0000000000000000 T exit_handler
0000000000000007 T main
```

Which seems to indicate the `atexit` symbol is there somewhere, but it does not appear in any of the libraries `ldd` is showing.

Comment: Try `gcc -c test.c; nm test.o` and see what symbols are referenced there.

Comment: Good idea:

```
$ nm test.o
                 U atexit
0000000000000000 T exit_handler
0000000000000007 T main
```

Comment: OK; that means it calls `atexit()` somehow.  Have you looked in `ld.so.1` (or, for you, perhaps `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`) for the symbol?  Or perhaps `crt0.o`, or whatever is linked?  You may need to run `gcc -v test.c` to see exactly what libraries and object files are linked.

Comment: Hmm...it doesn't appear to be there, as determined by: `$ nm --dynamic /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 | grep 'atexit'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did some poking around on a Centos 7 virtual machine, and I think I found it — but it was anything but obvious!

#### Found it!

In `/usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a`:

```
$ nm /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a | grep -i atexit
atexit.oS:
0000000000000000 T atexit
                 U __cxa_atexit
$
```

Why look in that library?  Good question — and a long story.  Are you sitting comfortably?  Then I'll begin…

#### Steps taken to get there

1. Use the `test.c` code from the question.
2. Compile it with `gcc -v test.c`:

   ```
   $ gcc -v test.c
   Using built-in specs.
   COLLECT_GCC=gcc
   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
   Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
   Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
   Thread model: posix
   gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) 
   COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
    /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/cc1 -quiet -v test.c -quiet -dumpbase test.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase test -version -o /tmp/ccPHTer7.s
   GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
       compiled by GNU C version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0.1
   GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=96 --param ggc-min-heapsize=124992
   ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include-fixed"
   ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
   #include "..." search starts here:
   #include <...> search starts here:
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include
    /usr/local/include
    /usr/include
   End of search list.
   GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
       compiled by GNU C version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0.1
   GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=96 --param ggc-min-heapsize=124992
   Compiler executable checksum: 356f86e67978d665416e07d560c8ba0d
   COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
    as -v --64 -o /tmp/cc5WHEA4.o /tmp/ccPHTer7.s
   GNU assembler version 2.25.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux) using BFD version version 2.25.1-22.base.el7 
   COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/
   LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
   COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
    /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/collect2 --build-id --no-add-needed --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../.. /tmp/cc5WHEA4.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
   $
   ```
3. The interesting part is the `collect2` command line at the end.  Written with one argument per line, that is:

   ```
   /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/collect2
   --build-id
   --no-add-needed
   --eh-frame-hdr
   --hash-style=gnu
   -m
   elf_x86_64
   -dynamic-linker
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crti.o
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtbegin.o
   -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5
   -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64
   -L/lib/../lib64
   -L/usr/lib/../lib64
   -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../..
   /tmp/cc5WHEA4.o
   -lgcc
   --as-needed
   -lgcc_s
   --no-as-needed
   -lc
   -lgcc
   --as-needed
   -lgcc_s
   --no-as-needed
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtend.o
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
   ```
4. So, there are a bunch of `cr*.o` files, plus three libraries: `-lc`, `-lgcc` and `-lgcc_s` to look for, and a bunch of directories to look in: 
   `-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5`, `-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64`, `-L/lib/../lib64`, `-L/usr/lib/../lib64`, `-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../..`.  The `/tmp/cc5WHEA4.o` is the object file created from `test.c`.
5. Applying some clean-up code to the path names, and then using `ls` to help find the libraries yields a list of files to examine further:

   ```
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
   /usr/lib64/crt1.o
   /usr/lib64/crti.o
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtbegin.o
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtend.o
   /usr/lib64/crtn.o
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libgcc.a
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libgcc_s.so
   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
   /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
   /usr/lib64/libc.so
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
   /lib64/libc.so
   /lib64/libc.so.6
   /usr/lib64/libc.so
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
   ```
6. That list of files was saved in a file `yy` (unimaginative name), and then used in:

   ```
   $ nm -o $(<yy) | tee nm.log | grep -i atexit
   nm: _trampoline.o: no symbols
   nm: __main.o: no symbols
   nm: _ctors.o: no symbols
   nm: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libgcc_s.so: no symbols
   nm: /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1: no symbols
   nm: /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1: no symbols
   nm: /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1: no symbols
   nm: /usr/lib64/libc.so: File format not recognized
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:00000000003bcc00 b added_atexit_handler.9157
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:0000000000038c90 T __cxa_atexit
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:0000000000038c90 t __cxa_atexit_internal
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:00000000003b6838 d __elf_set___libc_atexit_element__IO_cleanup__
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:0000000000038c40 t __internal_atexit
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:00000000003b6838 d __start___libc_atexit
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:00000000003b6840 d __stop___libc_atexit
   nm: /lib64/libc.so: File format not recognized
   /lib64/libc.so.6:00000000003bcc00 b added_atexit_handler.9157
   /lib64/libc.so.6:0000000000038c90 T __cxa_atexit
   /lib64/libc.so.6:0000000000038c90 t __cxa_atexit_internal
   /lib64/libc.so.6:00000000003b6838 d __elf_set___libc_atexit_element__IO_cleanup__
   /lib64/libc.so.6:0000000000038c40 t __internal_atexit
   nm: /usr/lib64/libc.so: File format not recognized
   /lib64/libc.so.6:00000000003b6838 d __start___libc_atexit
   /lib64/libc.so.6:00000000003b6840 d __stop___libc_atexit
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:00000000003bcc00 b added_atexit_handler.9157
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:0000000000038c90 T __cxa_atexit
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:0000000000038c90 t __cxa_atexit_internal
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:00000000003b6838 d __elf_set___libc_atexit_element__IO_cleanup__
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:0000000000038c40 t __internal_atexit
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:00000000003b6838 d __start___libc_atexit
   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:00000000003b6840 d __stop___libc_atexit
   $
   ```
7. There's no evidence of a plain `atexit` function there.  Where's it hiding, and what's with those 'File format not recognized' messages?

   ```
   $ file /usr/lib64/libc.so
   /usr/lib64/libc.so: ASCII text
   $
   ```
8. ASCII text?  What?

   ```
   $ cat /usr/lib64/libc.so
   /* GNU ld script
      Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
      the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
   OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
   GROUP ( /lib64/libc.so.6 /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ) )
   $
   ```
9. OK; what's in `/usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a`?

   ```
   $  nm /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a | grep -i atexit
   atexit.oS:
   0000000000000000 T atexit
                    U __cxa_atexit
   $
   ```

   **Bingo!** Found it!

So, it seems that the `collect2` linker used by GCC is able to load files not listed on the command line, and that one of those files is `/usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a`, and that this library has `atexit()` in it.  Consequently, you should be able to invoke `atexit()` because it is statically linked into the executable … unless there's some more black magic hidden away here that I've not sussed out.

Comment: Oh my, that is fantastic, thank you for digging that out, you are awesome.

Comment: Great work Jonathan. In case anyone is wondering "why the gymnastics?", here is why. It is so the __dso_handle (shared library handle) is available at every call to atexit(). This was implemented as an obscure compatibility feature for shared libraries. When a dlclose() is done to a shared library, any atexit() handlers registered by that specific shared lib get called before the lib is unmapped. This is accomplished by atexit() calling __cxa_atexit() with the extra __dso_handle. This is how glibc pulls it off. Other systems (BSD, Apple) use different techniques to achieve the same goal.